# Python C API: Dictionary not parsing properly

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, dictionary

I am executing a python function from C. The function returns a dictionary, which I was hoping to map to a C++ map.

When I call PyObject_Str, I get a perfect string representation of the dictionary. However, PyDict_Check says it's not a dictionary:

```
        // Call the function
    PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(1,PyString_FromString((const char *) blob_pointer)); // argument is irrelevant for the question
    PyObject *dict = PyObject_CallObject(serialize_func, args);
    Py_DecRef(args);

    // THIS PRINTS A DICT!?!
    std::cout << PyString_AsString(PyObject_Str(dict)) << std::endl;

    //Nope
    if (dict == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Return value was null!" << std::endl;
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    std::cout << "Called python function" << std::endl;

    // Returns false!
    if (!PyDict_Check(dict)) {
        PyErr_Print();
        std::cout << "serialized value was not a dict" << std::endl;
        Py_DecRef(dict);
        return true;
    }
```

Output:

```
{...} // The expected dictionary
Called python function
serialized value was not a dict
Done.
```

Why is this happening? Is it a bug in the Python C API or am I missing something?

The python version is 2.7.13.

**EDIT**

I ended up using an ugly workaround of getting the string representation and building a c++ map from it. I would still like to know why the code behaved the way it did though.

Comment: That function name is suspect; serialization usually results in a string.

Comment: Don't worry, it's definitely a dictionary.

Comment: Check the charset encoding of a dictionary string. Have special (invalid) chars?, post the json string for check the result. I canot reproduce it. I think the json text is not right.